# Transferring multiple strings between Fragments of the same activity with tags

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am having trouble figuring out how to share data between my two fragments which are hosted on the same activity.

**The objective:** 
I want to transfer string from the the selected position of a spinner and an image url string from a selected list view position from fragment A to fragment B.

**The Attempt:**
I read the fragments doc on this problem here http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity 
And went ahead an created the following Interface to use betweeen the Fragments and the Host Activity.

```
public interface OnSelectionListener {
public void OnSelectionListener(String img, String comments );
```

}

Then I proceeded to implement it in my fragment A's onCreateView method like so:

```
  postList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {

            ListData link = data.get(position);
            String permalink = link.getComments();
            String largeImg = link.getImageUrl();



            Fragment newFragment = new DetailsView();

            FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

            // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
            // and add the transaction to the back stack
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);

            // Commit the transaction
            transaction.commit();

                //pass data to host activity
            selectionListener.OnSelectionListener(permalink,largeImg);


        }
    });
```

And also in the onAttach method

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        selectionListener = (OnSelectionListener)getActivity();
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement onSelectionListener");
    }
}
```

In the **Host** activity I implemented the interface I wrote and overrided the method like so:

```
 @Override
public void OnSelectionListener(String img, String comments) {
    DetailsView detailsView = new DetailsView();
    DetailsView dView = (DetailsView)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(detailsView.getCustomTag());
    dView.setInformation(img, comments);
}
```

In Fragment B I set a "tag" the following way

```
 private String tag;

public void setCustomTag(String tag)
{
    this.tag = tag;
}

public String getCustomTag()
{
    return tag;
}



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setCustomTag("DETAILS_VIEW");
```

And my thinking is that that the information can be passed to Fragment B by calling this method from the host activity

```
 void setInformation (String info, String img){
    RedditDetailsTask detailsTask = new RedditDetailsTask(null,DetailsView.this);
    detailsTask.execute(info);
    setDrawable(img);
}
```

**What I need:**
I want to know how to properly use **tags** to get this to work, I dont have any fragment id's declared in my xml and rather opted to exchange fragments in a fragment_container.

I also am not sure if this is a good way to pass multiple strings between fragments. I am a newbie programmer so I know my logic probably looks pretty embarrassing but I am trying to do my best learn to do this right. I would appreciate it if you more senior developers can point me in the right direction for doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach would be, when you get the callback in activity through the OnSelectionListener interface, I would create the Fragment B object and set arguments to it as follows:

```
 @Override
 public void OnSelectionListener(String img, String comments) {
  DetailsView detailsView = new DetailsView();
  Bundle args=new Bundle();
  args.putString("img",img);
  args.putString("comments",comments);
  detailsView.setArguments(args);
  //code here to replace the fragment A with fragment B

  }
```

Then in Fragment B's onCreate method you can retrieve the values as follows:

```
  @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  Bundle args=getArguments();
  String img=args.getString("img");
  String comments=args.getString("comments");
  //do whatever you want to do with the varaibles

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use tags. Take a look at this example. The Activity implements an interface that allows you to talk from Fragment1 back to the Activity, the Activity then relays the information into Fragment2.

I've left out all the android stuff about FragmentManager etc.

```
interface FragmentListener {

    void onTalk(String s1);

}

public class MyActivity extends Activity implements FragmentListener {

    Fragment2 fragment2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
        // Find fragment2 and init
    }

    @Override
    public void onTalk(String s1) {
        fragment2.onListen(s1);
    }

    private static class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

        private FragmentListener communication;

        @Override
        public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
            super.onAttach(activity);
            communication = (FragmentListener) activity;
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
        }

        @Override
        public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
            // or in an onClick listener
            communication.onTalk("blah blah");
        }
    }

    private static class Fragment2 extends Fragment {

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two, container, false);
        }

        public void onListen(String s1) {
            Log.d("TADA", s1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to make two public static String's in your B fragment.

it Would look like something like this

```
public static String img;
public static String comment;
```

The you set the variables before making the transaction to fragment B

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

// Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
// and add the transaction to the back stack
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);

SecondFragment.img = new String("imgString"); //Making a new string so incase you change the string in bfragment, the values wont change in here
SecondFragment.comment = new String("comment");

// Commit the transaction
transaction.commit();
```

Then in the onStop(), or onDestroy() - depending on when you want the variables to be null, [check this](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/platform_features/fragments/part_1_-_creating_a_fragment/Images/fragment_lifecycle.png) - you set the the static variables to null, so they dont take memory space

```
public void onDestroy(){
   super.onDestroy();
   img = null;
   comment = null;
}
```